# Multi-list comprehension

Tags: python

Given the following data structure, how would I get the max length of the characters inside it?

```
data = [['a', 'b'], ['cc', 'dd']]
```

The largest item is 'cc' so the answer would be 2. Here is what I have so far, but it is incorrect.

```
max_chars = [len(item) for item for item in data]
```

Comment: Google how to flatten a list of lists and how to use `max()` with key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
max_chars = max(len(item) for lst in data for item in lst)
```

Comment: You can even drop the `[ ]` :-)

Answer (score 1):

I dislike nested list comprehensions.  They're hard to read.

Using itertools, you can flatten the data and then find the max length.

```
import itertools
flat = itertools.chain(*data)
result = max(len(i) for i in flat)
```

Note that `flat` is an iterable object that's difficult to inspect, but `list(flat)` returns `['a', 'b', 'cc', 'dd']`

Answer (score 0):

Max takes a `key` function:

```
>>> max([['a', 'b'], ['cc', 'dd']], key=lambda l: max(len(e) for e in l))
['cc', 'dd']
>>> max([['a', 'bbb'], ['cc', 'dd']], key=lambda l: max(len(e) for e in l))
['a', 'bbb']
```

That prints the sublist with the longest element. If you want the value of the length and the index of the individual sublist, you could do:

```
>>> data=[['a', 'bbb'], ['cc', 'dd']]
>>> maxes=((i, len(max(l, key=len))) for i, l in enumerate(data))
>>> max(maxes, key=lambda t:t[1])
(0, 3)           # first element is the sublist index, second the length
```

Comment: This returns the sublist with the longest **first** item -- e.g if `data=[['x','weeeeeee'], ['yy', 'x']]` this returns the second sublist.  This seems light years away from what the OP's was asking for.

Comment: Try this with the following input:  `[['a', 'bbbbbbb'], ['cc', 'dd']]`  I think your answer will return `['cc', 'dd']` which I'm pretty sure isn't what OP wants no matter how you slice it :-)